# Структуры в Си (Xcode). Не могу присвоить значения полям структуры. В чем проблема?

Tags: c, xcode, структуры

Не понятно в чем заключается проблема. Не могу присвоить полям структуры значения. Пробовал и так, и эдак. Не выходит... Такая проста штука вроде бы, но что-то я упускаю, Xcode ругается.

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct
 {
     char name[50];         // Имя
     char surname[50];      // Фамилия
     char patronymic[50];   // Отчество
 } FCs;
 typedef struct
 {
     char street[100];      // Улица
     int house;             // Дом
     int apartament;        // Квартира
 } Adress;

 typedef struct
 {
     int bYear;             // Год рождения
     Adress adr;            // Структура адреса
     FCs fcs;               // Структура ФИО
 } General;

General j = {1999, {"Proletarskaya"}, 100, 1, {"Ivan"}, {"Ivanov"}, {"Ivanovich"} };  // Не получается
j.adr = {"Proletarskaya", 100, 1};  // Так тоже не выходит


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

[image: Ошибки, которые показывает компилятор]

Comment: `{}` лишнее вокруг каждого строчного литерала. Ну и потом пропущены `{}` для указания вложенных структур. Лучше всего использовать C99 инициализацию (с указанием имени поля), типа `{ .adr = { .street = "Улочка моя", ...}, ... }`. Потом почитать про *compound literals* не помешает.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!!

Answer (score 1):

В первом случае нужно фигурные скобки ставить правильно. Во втором : команды могут находится только в теле функции. Справа после присвоения в фигурных скобках вы создаёте *временную* структуру и потом её присваиваете полю `j.adr`. Этой временной структуре нужно указывать её тип в скобках.

```
General j = {1999, {"Proletarskaya", 100, 1}, {"Ivan", "Ivanov", "Ivanovich"} };

int main()
{    
    j.adr = (Adress){"Proletarskaya", 100, 1};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема была решена путем удаления лишних скобочек в литералах. Странно, ведь я пробовал удалять их, но ничего не выходило. Магия, чистая магия.

Comment: удалите это, напишите комментарием